# Middle node of Singly linked List

Tags: c++, list

I found this code to print the middle node of a list in C++ but I don't understand the code...Someone can explain me this?

```
    Type& findMiddleNode()
{
    int check = 0;
    nodeType *current;
    nodeType *mid;

    current = first;
    mid = first;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        current = current->link;
        check = (check + 1) % 2;

        if (check == 0)
            mid = mid->link;
    }

    return mid->info;
}
```

PD: This code works perfect, but I dont understand! Someone help me to understand this. Thanks!

Comment: What do you not understand exactly? We can give better help if you say so :)

Comment: The idea is to have two pointers that traverse the list at different speeds, one twice as fast as the other. The fast pointer is advanced on every iteration, the slow pointer only every other iteration. When the fast pointer reaches the end of the list, the slow one would be exactly in the middle.

Comment: I dont understand the function of the pointers current and mid, and the var current. I dont understand the process in the while loop

Comment: @JhonnyAfonso [tag:c] doesn't have the `&` operator, only for taking address it's valid.

Comment: Ok, my confusion its in the line check = (check+1)%2; and in the If statement. In the while, the current pointer run all the list and the mid pointer run to exactly middle of list? Im correct?

Comment: @JhonnyAfonso Inspect the code with the debugger, to get a grip what it actually does.

Comment: `check` simply alternates between 0 and 1. That's how `mid` pointer is only advanced every other iteration.

Comment: So, in the while, the current pointer run all the list and the mid pointer run to exactly middle of list? Im correct?

Comment: @JhonnyAfonso Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok, I understood the code, I drawed the iteration in a paper and I understand better! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to move two pointers B and A through the list, but with B moving at only half the speed of A.

The statement

```
check = (check + 1) % 2;
```

… gives `check` the values 0, 1, 0, 1 and so on, which is used to move B only every second time A is moved.

The same idea is one possible (and expected) answer to a question about checking whether a singly linked list contains a loop. In this case the fast moving pointer will catch up with the slow one after both have entered the loop.

---

A simpler way to do the same, with just about the same work expended by the program, is to (1) count the number of nodes *n*, and (2) starting at the start again, go to node number *n*/2.

Step (1) moves a pointer *n* times, like A above, and step (2) moves a pointer *n*/2 times, like B above.